# Are mysql multiple inserts within a Single query atomic?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update, atomic

I'm doing multiple inserts in a **single** query:

```
INSERT INTO table (c1, c2) VALUES (1,2),
                                  (2,3),
                                  (3,4),......
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c2 = VALUES(c2)
```

Now suppose that there's over tens of thousands of VALUES specified in the query (hence the ellipsis)....

Can there ever be a case in which some parts of the VALUES managed to get inserted/updated in the database but the rest did not get inserted/updated possibly due to some sort of db error/failure/memory-running-out etc?

**Are mysql queries ALL or Nothing?**

Is it true that for every mysql query executed, either all values specified in the query will be inserted/updated smoothly, or none of the values will be inserted/updated?

Comment: A single call to `insert` should be atomic in any ACID-compliant database.

Comment: Why don't you test it - you don't need hundreds of datapoints to test it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is join insert/update on MySQL an atomic operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444623/is-join-insert-update-on-mysql-an-atomic-operation)

Comment: @GordonLinoff MyISAM tables aren't acid compliant though ;)

Comment: @gvee almost impossible to test, as it is with all race conditions. with some luck., you can run 10000 tests in a non acid compliant systems and still have consistent data.

Comment: @JohannesH. . . . Well, I guess that answers the question.  I don't see this in the MySQL documentation, but I do see it at http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-engines-myisam-vs-innodb.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Specification link is in my answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)   (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) properties are used to describe such behaviour in databases. Atomicity is only important if we're dealing with [concurrent modifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control). To ensure Consistency, a certain level of Isolation must be reached. The more isolated multiple transactions run, however, the less performance the DBMS usually has. So there is the so called "[isolation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28computer_science%29#Isolation_levels)", which states what errors can possibly occur in a DBMS and which cannot.

Now, MySQL implements all isolation levels in INNODB databases, and you can choose for each transaction: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html

MyIsam databases don't support transactions, single operations should however run atomically. (Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html). Note however, that this does NOT guarantee data isn't changed between the reads and writes in one operation - atomicity in DBMS terms only means that the operation is either completely done or completely skipped. It does NOT guarantee isolation, consistency or durability.

Comment: May I kindly ask what the downvote was for? I don't see any comments or edit-suggestions...

Comment: . . . There are malicious downvoters out there.  I think this is a good answer.  +1.

Comment: @JohannesH. It might be because the MySQL link pointed to the German docs =) Fixed it.

Comment: Oh. I didn't even realize! Thanks!

Comment: @JohannesH., So in the above example if we are using Innodb, do you mean that a 1000 row insert would either be All or Nothing? Is it possible for a half amount e.g. 300, 500, or 800 rows to be inserted?

Comment: @Pacerier If it's a transaction, then it's either commited or rolled back completely. What that means depends on the isolation level you chose.

Comment: @JohannesH., No it's in an explicit transaction. It's just a normal **single** insert statement. Do single statements that insert thousands of rows enjoy the benefit of "commit or rolled back completely"?

Comment: With autocommit on (which is the default) you're in a transaction, so yes. If you turned it off (for performance reasons or whatever), it strongly depends on what you mean by "all or nothing". Are crashs possible? Do you ahve simultaneous operations running? But in general, you can't count on it.

Comment: If I run a php script that insert multiple rows in mysql db. Let's suppose it takes around 5 seconds.  In between 5 seconds I close the script i.e. close the php page in browser or aborts the script in console. Then how may rows will get inserted in db. Also tell answer for 2 possible use cases. One is if multiple mysql queries insert many many multiple rows and second, if single mysql query inserts multiple rows. `Please answer. May the force be with you`.

Comment: @Ankit Fist of all: if any database operation takes 5 seconds, you should seriously consider other solutions for whatever you do. 
Second: If all statements were already sent to the database server (weith asynchronous execution for example tihs is possible), they will execute, even if the script ends running. If they were not, it depends on how many instructions were sent. If you used a transaction and the scrript dies before the commit, changes will be rolled back (aka no changes are there at the end). If not, whatever happened happened, whatever didn't happen yet won't.

Comment: @Ankit: To answer specifically to your use-cases, we'd need more information about your server stack, which PHP libraries you use and on your code. PLEASE make it a separate quesiton in this case (feel free to point me towards it if you do)

Comment: -1 for "single operations should however run atomically". Should? Is a multi-row insert atomic or not? That was the question - this post does not answer it.

Answer (score 5):

*"Can there ever be a case in which some parts of the VALUES managed to get inserted/updated in the database but the rest did not get inserted/updated possibly due to some sort of db error/failure/memory-running-out etc?"*

Late answer, but perhaps interesting: `[ON DUPLICATE KEY] UPDATE` is not *strictly* atomic for single rows (neither for `MyISAM`, nor for `InnoDB`), but it will be atomic in regards to errors.

What's the difference? Well, this illustrates the potential problem in assuming strict atomicity:

```
CREATE TABLE `updateTest` (
  `bar` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `foo` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `baz` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `boom` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bar`)
)
COMMENT='Testing'
ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `updateTest` (`bar`, `foo`, `baz`, `boom`) VALUES (47, 1, 450, 2);

INSERT
    `updateTest`
    (`bar`, `foo`, `baz`, `boom`)
VALUES
    (47, 0, 400, 5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `foo` = IF(`foo` = 1, VALUES(`foo`), `foo`),
    `baz` = IF(`foo` = 1, VALUES(`baz`), `baz`),
    `boom` = IF(`foo` = 1, VALUES(`boom`), `boom`);
```

`(47, 1, 450, 2)` will have turned into `(47, 0, 450, 2)`, and not into `(47, 0, 400, 5)`. If you assume *strict atomicity* (which is not to say you should; you might prefer this behaviour), that shouldn't happen - `foo` should certainly not change before the other columns' values are even *evaluated*. `foo` should change together with the other columns - *all or nothing*.

If I say *atomic in regards to errors*, I mean that if you remove the `IF()` condition in the above example that's highlighting the stricter situation, like this...

```
INSERT INTO `updateTest` (`bar`, `foo`, `baz`, `boom`) VALUES (48, 1, 450, 2);

INSERT
    `updateTest`
    (`bar`, `foo`, `baz`, `boom`)
VALUES
    (48, 0, 400, 5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `foo` = VALUES(`foo`),
    `baz` = VALUES(`baz`),
    `boom` = VALUES(`boom`);
```

...you will always *either* end up with `(48, 1, 450, 2)` *or* `(48, 0, 400, 5)` after your statement has finished/crashed, and *not* some in-between state like `(48, 0, 450, 2)`.

The same is true for the behaviour of `UPDATE`, but there's even less of a reason to juggle `IF()` statements there, since you can just put your conditionals into your `WHERE` clause there.

In conclusion: Outside of edge-cases, you do have atomicity for single-row statements, even using `MyISAM`. See [Johannes H.'s answer for further information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21584504/245790).

Answer (score 1):

It the table storage engine is [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html), yes, the operation is definitely atomic and a partial insert is not possible. I believe this is not true with MyISAM, the default engine, since it is not ACID-compliant and doesn't support transactions.

Comment: MyISAM is atomic, however not necessarily consistent, durable or isolated. See my answer.

Comment: MyISAM is **not** atomic, as the term generally applies to database systems.

Comment: @MarcusAdams See your point. Agreed, that should be "MyISAM databases implement 'atomic operations' as integrity scheme". It's more like "atomic" in the way it's used outside DBMS terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Single statements such as this are. If you need multiple calls to act in an atomic manner you may use [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) in most relational databases.

Comment: As this is specifically about MySQL this means, one have to use INNODB tables, as MyIsam doesn't support transactions.

Comment: I'd say that if you're asking this question you should be using InnoDB. If data integrity is paramount then InnoDB is almost always better.

Comment: Totally with you on that one, though OP amy not know. In addtion to that, as we're talking about huge amount of data (according to the OP), speed may be an issue, though there is a point for MyISAM.