# Yii2: How to get each record primary key by adding multiple row using batchInsert?

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm using this batchInsert command to add multiple row at once. I want to get each record primary Key(Last Insert Id). How can I do this?

```
  $insertCount = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
             ->batchInsert(
             Testuser::tableName(), $columnNameArray,$bulkInsertArray)
->execute();
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no reliable way to get _all_ IDs when batch inserting. I can't think of anything other than assigning a special column a particular value when inserting, and then getting back all IDs for that value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that id column is AUTO_INCREMENT.
So we can get last inserted id and then calculate first inserted id (corrected):

```
$firstId = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();
$lastId  = $firstId + $insertCount - 1;
```

Then inserted rows have ids from $firstId to $lastId.
As it turned out last insert id returns id of first inserted row when batch insert was made.

Comment: This is not reliable - there are cases when this approach will fail miserably.

Comment: I'd like to know more about it. Can you provide some info, please?

Comment: Do you have proof that bulk insert into an table is an atomic operation? If not, two concurrent inserts will break your logic.

Comment: Bulk insert is atomic according to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584207/are-mysql-multiple-inserts-within-a-single-query-atomic
Though atomicity doesn't guarantee that ids will have successive values.
But "When accessing the auto-increment counter, InnoDB uses a special table-level AUTO-INC lock that it keeps to the end of the current SQL statement" and "two transactions cannot have the AUTO-INC lock on the same table simultaneously".
So it seems guarantees successive ids values.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-traditional.html

Comment: I admit, you're right. The answer still makes me uneasy, because there's no guarantee the underlying system is actually MySQL and that it's actually using InnoDB. If I were to code something like that, I'd rather stay on the safe side and not assume that automatically generated IDs are sequential.