# Counter that counts the no. of time user login

Tags: php, mysql

**MY HOME PAGE**

```
$val="SELECT Visit FROM signup WHERE Name = '$myusername'";
            $rlt = mysqli_query($conn,$val);
      $rw= mysqli_fetch_array($rlt,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
          $inc=++$rw["Visit"];
      $valnew="UPDATE table signup set Visit =$inc where Name=$myusername "
  mysqli_query($conn,$valnew); 
      $_SESSION['query'] = $inc;
```

**After login Page**

```
$check = $_SESSION['query'];
   echo "You are visiting this page".$check." times";
```

motive:  - when the user logged in, will able to see his no. of visits.

problem: update query is not working, that's why always echo 1-time visit.

Comment: `UPDATE table signup` replace with `UPDATE signup`

Comment: still not working :( @cske

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update query is wrong, First test your query on localhost phpmyadmin and then try to integrate it in your code.

change

```
UPDATE table signup set Visit =$inc where Name=$myusername
```

to

```
UPDATE signup set Visit =$inc where Name='$myusername';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the self-increment of MySQL to make this feasible.

`UPDATE` query should be in the form like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column={value} WHERE {case}
```

Also, when the query condition is not numerical, and without data binding, you should quote it with `quotation marks`.

```
$valnew = "UPDATE signup set Visit=Visit+1 where Name='{$myusername}'";
```

Also, your original code has a problem of atomicity, with this code, will make the increment query atomic.

Learn more about ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584207/are-mysql-multiple-inserts-within-a-single-query-atomic).

Comment: didn't get you, self-increment would increase the value as records increases?
I want to increase for single record as many time user login

Comment: This query will give increment to `Visit` each time it is executed.

Comment: yea now got you. Thankyou :) @haotian